# Spark jobserver is not finishing YARN processes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, spark-jobserver

I have configured Spark jobserver to run on YARN.
I am able to send spark jobs to YARN but even after the job finishes it does not quit on YARN

For eg: 
I tried to make a simple spark context.
The context is reflecting in jobserver but YARN is still running the process and is not quieting I have to manually kill the tasks.

**Yarn Job**

[image: Yarn Job]

**Spark Context**
[image: Spark Context]

Job server reflects the contexts but as soon as I try to run any task in it Job server give me an error

```
{
  "status": "ERROR",
  "result": "context test-context2 not found"
}
```

My Spark UI is also not very helpful

[image: Spark Ui]

Comment: Can you provide more information like, info from spark-jobserver log at the time of execution?